# Contains(.,'text') function for matching text

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select things in a table, and currently have the following expression

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[contains(., 'user2')]/td[contains(., 'user2')]
```

however, this is obviously a problem when there are users entered such as 'user 25', because that also contains 'user 2'. Can someone help me fix what's wrong with the following expressions in which I tried to match the text values exactly? (just the row for now)

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[text()='user2']
```

I tried normalizing space too, didn't seem to work

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[normalize-space(text())='user2']
```

If it will help here is the html of the page

```
<table id="row" class="gradientTable">

<td>
                                user2


                        </td>
<td>User2</td>
<td>User2</td>
<td>user2@mail.com</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Student</td></tr>
<tr class="even">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[.//text()[normalize-space(.)='user2']]
```

matches any `<tr>` for which *any single descendant text node* has the exact content `user2` (after space normalization).

Note that this won't match anything in your example html. That example seems to be broken, because there's only one `<tr>` there, and it has no content that we can see.

## Addendum:

You asked, "how exactly does .//text()[] work"?

- `.` selects the context node (which in the above case is a `tr` element).
- `//text()` selects any text node that is a descendant (of the aforementioned `tr` element).
- `[...]` gives a predicate that "filters" what the preceding expression selects. So in this case it filters all text nodes that are descendants of the context `tr`, keeping only those whose space-normalized text content is 'user2'.
- All this, as a predicate for `tr`, means to filter the `tr` elements, keeping only those for which there is at least one descendant text node whose space-normalized text content is 'user2'.

As Michael Kay pointed out, that may or may not be exactly what you want, depending on whether you want to match a table cell that contains `user2` spread across `b` or `i` elements.

## Addendum 2:

> Can someone help me fix what's wrong with the following expressions in
>   which I tried to match the text values exactly? (just the row for now)

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[text()='user2']
```

What this expression matches is `tr` elements that have a direct **child** (not grandchild) text node whose value is exactly 'user2', e.g. `<tr>textNode1<td>...</td>user2</tr>`. Since text in tables is usually in a `td` element instead of directly under a `tr`, the above expression typically matches nothing.

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[normalize-space(text())='user2']
```

Aside from space normalization, this expression also collapses the generality of the `=` comparison. In other words... The previous XPath expression asks whether the `tr` element has *any* text node child whose value is `user2`; but this one only asks whether the `tr` element's *first* text node child has a value `user2`.

Why? Because the `normalize-space()` function takes a single string value as its argument. So if you supply `text()` as the argument, and there are several `text()` children, you are supplying a node-set (or sequence in XPath 2.0). The node-set gets [converted to a string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) by taking [the string-value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the **first** node in the node-set.

To get a general comparison back, with normalization, you would use

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[text()[normalize-space(.)='user2']]
```

(The `.` argument is the default anyway, but I prefer making it explicit.) Again, this will only work with text nodes that are direct children of `tr`, so you'll probably want a descendant axis in there:

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr[.//text()[normalize-space(.)='user2']]
```

Comment: thanks, that expression does select the row I was looking for. I'm kind of new to xpath, how exactly does .//text()[] work, I have not seen that in the numerous tutorials I have looked up

Comment: This seems wrong to me, the original query was selecting td elements, whereas this one is selecting tr elements. Also, text() should be avoided, especially with HTML-like content, because it won't catch cases where there is internal markup within a table cell (e.g. italics or bold)

Comment: @MichaelKay: The OP's 2nd and 3rd expressions select `tr` elements. What he actually wants to select is unclear to me. You're right of course that `text()` might not be the right approach for the OP's requirements; or it might be exactly what he needs. He does say "match the text values exactly." I thought I'd take the above stab, and let him give further clarification if it wasn't what was needed... rather than go too far with speculation.

Comment: thank you, this has been very helpful! And sorry about the unclarity, I mentioned that I wanted to select only the row in my 2nd and 3rd statements which I believe is the tr, but in the future I will definetely state so more explicitly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the table cells (td) elements that contain the exact value "user 2", then you want

```
//*[@id='row']/tbody/tr/td[. = 'user2']
```

People often misuse "contains" here because they think it has the same meaning as in the English sentence above, "a node contains a value". But that's what "=" does in XPath; the XPath contains() function tests whether the content of the node has a substring equal to "user2".

Don't use `text()` here. The `text()` expression selects individual text nodes. But your content isn't necessarily all part of the same text node, for example it might be `"user<b>2</b>"`.